# Flutter android equivalent of scaleX and scaleY property

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

In Android, I can use `scaleX` and `scaleY` property but in Flutter I can't find anything like that.

There is `Transform.scale()` but it combines both `scaleX` and `scaleY` and what I need is just `scaleX`. I know Perspective can help but it's too much for just `scaleX` property. Anyone with better answer?

Comment: I know SizedBox thanks but are you sure you are talking about scale here? Because I am not talking about width and height.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the easiest way is to see how `Transform.scale` constructor works and use it in your custom `Transform`:

```
Transform.scale({
     Key key,
     @required double scale,
     this.origin,
     this.alignment = Alignment.center,
     this.transformHitTests = true,
     Widget child,
   }) : transform = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(scale, scale, 1.0),
       super(key: key, child: child);
```

it scales both `x` and `y` so if you want only `x` axis to be scaled just use the following:

```
Transform(
  transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(scale, 1.0, 1.0),
  child: ....,)
```